migration from x86 - Apple Silicon - problems with ~/Library/Python/3.12 x86 leftovers
Just moved from an X86 mac to an M3 and having some problems with the ~/Library/Python/3.12 directory.
What I did so far:

restored from Time Machine

home only
left /Applications/ behind, figuring that's all x86 and only want to Rosetta when necessary


installed python3.12 (from macports, and then then directly from python.org)


All went well.  Installed uv too, and got a venv running.  Python 3.12 is live and looks good.
Except that, when I call ruff I get a notice about bad CPU.
Sure enough I have 3.12 python executables that got carried over in ~/Library/Python:
3.12
├── bin
├── etc
│   └── jupyter
├── include
│   └── python3.12
├── lib
│   └── python
└── share
    ├── applications
    ├── icons
    ├── jupyter
    └── man

OK, and yes, sure enough, there is an old bin/ruff.  All this stuff got restored from Time Machine.
OK, I think, rm that 3.12 and reinstall Python 3.12.
Again, all goes well, except that none of the installs recreated a ~/Library/Python/3.12.  So, I can pip install ruff successfully, but nothing gets deposited in Python/3.12.
That's after a reinstall from macports and a reinstall from python.org. I also tried to recreate the 3.12 directory structure, empty.  Didn't help.
How do I fix this installation?
Note:  I do not wish to use brew for a python installation.
note:  This is what the 3.11 bin structure looks like.  Note that ruff is a file, not a symlink.
/Users/me/Library/Python/3.11/bin
me@Mac bin % lsl ruff
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me  staff  18915192 31 Jan  2024 ruff


I think the issue is weather you are installing ruff - pip on its own installs to a global space e.g. /Library/Python/... the ones in your home directory need to be installed by using the --user flag e,g, python -m pip install ruff

Well, one thing I found is that ruff does get installed in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin.  Adding this to the $PATH solved my immediate issue, I'll backtrack to check if this directory existed in my older Macos (I think it was Big Sur, so a while back).  Note that /Users/me/Library/Python would have been a global, not a venv specific.  I tend to install tools globally and this was by design in the case of ruff.

I would just delete all the python and then reinstall from python.org. (FWIW, I don't have any python in my User Library; it's all in /Library.) Also, most apps in your Applications folder are likely to be Universal Binaries, so assuming that it's all X86 is not certain.

@JLPeyret my use of global is meaning it is available to all users. ~/Library is only for the current user and so is not global.

The issue is that pip by default installs into the global directory accessible by all users in /Library/Python/...
To install for one user (which would be ~/Library/Python you need to add the --user flag.
So for ruff for just yourself you should run
python -m pip install ruff 

